# Pinax vs. Plone -- Dev time, flexibility, security?

Tags: django, plone, zope, pinax

Trying to evaluate Pinax vs. Plone as platforms for developing a social network with some RIA capabilities and a solid permissions setup allowing the user to make content visible on a per item/group basis.

Would I be better off hacking Plone (and having to learn Zope, etc) or adding on/modifying Pinax with existing/new Django? Trying to weigh dev time, flexibility and existing strengths such as security in Plone.

Thanks!

Comment: Go an answer on the security question on the pinax-mailist: security is quite good on pinax thanks to django. plone is great as a cms not so good as a social network tool. this from an ex-plone developer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use all of the functionality of Pinax - then Pinax would be the best choice. Look at cloud27.com - it used Pinax and that site could be replicated very quickly with Pinax. Like 5 mins quickly.

But if you are going to scale it back, then it might be more work to undo than to build in straight django applications.

Plone is really a great CMS and not for a social network.